# Pandas Custom Sort Row in Multiindex

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, multi-index

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'],
          ['total', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'four', 'total', 'five']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(7), index=index)
s

first  second
bar    total     0.334158
       two      -0.267854
       one       1.161727
baz    two      -0.748685
       four     -0.888634
       total     0.383310
       five      0.506120
dtype: float64
```

How do I ensure that the 'total' rows (per the second index) are always at the bottom of each group like this?:

```
first  second
bar    one       0.210911
       two       0.628357
       total    -0.911331
baz    two       0.315396
       four     -0.195451
       five      0.060159
       total     0.638313
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The easiest option is to call it `"~total"` or `"|total|"` or `"{total}"`. Then it will always get sorted to the bottom.

Comment: Please do not mention deadlines in your questions: remember that nearly everyone who answers is a volunteer.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for creating `DataFrame` with columns with second level of `MultiIndex`, then reorder columns for `total` to last column and last use ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html).

So if [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) level `total` is last.

```
np.random.seed(123)
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'],
          ['total', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'four', 'total', 'five']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(7), index=index)
print (s)
first  second
bar    total    -1.085631
       two       0.997345
       one       0.282978
baz    two      -1.506295
       four     -0.578600
       total     1.651437
       five     -2.426679
dtype: float64
```

```
df = s.unstack()
df = df[df.columns[df.columns != 'total'].tolist() + ['total']]
df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns, ordered=True)
print (df)
second      five    four       one       two     total
first                                                 
bar          NaN     NaN  0.282978  0.997345 -1.085631
baz    -2.426679 -0.5786       NaN -1.506295  1.651437
```

```
s1 = df.stack()
print (s1)
first  second
bar    one       0.282978
       two       0.997345
       total    -1.085631
baz    five     -2.426679
       four     -0.578600
       two      -1.506295
       total     1.651437
dtype: float64

print (s1.sort_index())
first  second
bar    one       0.282978
       two       0.997345
       total    -1.085631
baz    five     -2.426679
       four     -0.578600
       two      -1.506295
       total     1.651437
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

### solution 1

I'm not happy with this.  I'm working on a different solution

```
unstacked = s.unstack(0)
total = unstacked.loc['total']
unstacked.drop('total').append(total).unstack().dropna()

first  second
bar    one       1.682996
       two       0.343783
       total     1.287503
baz    five      0.360170
       four      1.113498
       two       0.083691
       total    -0.377132
dtype: float64
```

### solution 2

I feel better about this one

```
second = pd.Categorical(
    s.index.levels[1].values,
    categories=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'total'],
    ordered=True
)
s.index.set_levels(second, level='second', inplace=True)

cols = s.index.names
s.reset_index().sort_values(cols).set_index(cols)

                     0
first second          
bar   one     1.682996
      two     0.343783
      total   1.287503
baz   two     0.083691
      four    1.113498
      five    0.360170
      total  -0.377132
```